# use directories or all files in directories as input in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I am new to snakemake. I want to use directories or all files in directories as input in snakemake. For example, two directories with different no. of bam files,

```
--M1
    M1-1.bam
    M1-2.bam
--M2
    M2-3.bam
    M2-5.bam
```

I just want to merge M1-1.bam, M1-2.bam to M1.bam; M2-3.bam, M2-5.bam to M2.bam; I tried to use `wildcards` and `expand` followd by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51855608/how-to-collect-snakemake-input-files-that-match-wildcard-with-the-input-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908069/snakemake-output-one-only-file-from-multiple-input-files-in-one-rule), and the code is as follows,

config.yaml

```
SAMPLES:
  M1:
    - 1
    - 2
  M2:
    - 3
    - 5
rawdata: path/to/rawdata
outpath: path/to/output
reference: path/to/reference
```

snakemake file

```
configfile:"config.yaml"
SAMPLES=config["SAMPLES"]
REFERENCE=config["reference"]
RAWDATA=config["rawdata"]
OUTPATH=config["outpath"]

ALL_INPUT = []
for key, values in SAMPLES.items():
    ALL_INPUT.append(f"Map/bwa/merge/{key}.bam")
    ALL_INPUT.append(f"Map/bwa/sort/{key}.sort.bam")
    ALL_INPUT.append(f"Map/bwa/dup/{key}.sort.rmdup.bam")
    ALL_INPUT.append(f"Map/bwa/dup/{key}.sort.rmdup.matrix")
    ALL_INPUT.append(f"SNV/Mutect2/result/{key}.vcf.gz")
    ALL_INPUT.append(f"Map/bwa/result/{key}")
    for value in values:
        ALL_INPUT.append(f"Map/bwa/result/{key}/{key}-{value}.bam")
        for num in {1,2}:
            ALL_INPUT.append(f"QC/fastp/{key}/{key}-{value}.R{num}.fastq.gz")

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{outpath}/{all_input}",all_input=ALL_INPUT,outpath=OUTPATH)
        
rule fastp:
    input:
        r1= RAWDATA + "/{key}-{value}.R1.fastq.gz",
        r2= RAWDATA + "/{key}-{value}.R2.fastq.gz"
    output:
        a1="{outpath}/QC/fastp/{key}/{key}-{value}.R1.fastq.gz",
        a2="{outpath}/QC/fastp/{key}/{key}-{value}.R2.fastq.gz"
    params:
        prefix="{outpath}/QC/fastp/{key}/{key}-{value}"
    shell:
        """
        fastp -i {input.r1} -I {input.r2} -o {output.a1} -O {output.a2} -j {params.prefix}.json -h {params.prefix}.html
        """

rule bwa:
    input:
        a1="{outpath}/QC/fastp/{key}/{key}-{value}.R1.fastq.gz",
        a2="{outpath}/QC/fastp/{key}/{key}-{value}.R2.fastq.gz"
    output:
        o1="{outpath}/Map/bwa/result/{key}/{key}-{value}.bam"
    params:
        mem="4000",
        rg="@RG\\tID:{key}\\tPL:ILLUMINA\\tSM:{key}"
    shell:
        """
        bwa mem -t {threads} -M -R '{params.rg}' {REFERENCE} {input.a1} {input.a2} | samtools view -b -o {output.o1}
        """

## get sample index from raw fastq
key_ids,value_ids = glob_wildcards(RAWDATA + "/{key}-{value}.R1.fastq.gz")
# remove duplicate sample name, and this is useful when there is only one sample input
key_ids = list(set(key_ids))

rule merge:
    input:
        expand("{outpath}/Map/bwa/result/{key}/{key}-{value}.bam",outpath=OUTPATH, key=key_ids, value=value_ids)
    output:
        "{outpath}/Map/bwa/merge/{key}.bam"
    shell:
        """
        samtools merge {output} {input}
        """
```

The {input} in merge command will be

```
M1-1.bam M1-2.bam M1-3.bam M1-5.bam M2-1.bam M2-2.bam M2-3.bam M2-5.bam
```

Actually, for M1 sample, the {input} should be `M1-1.bam M1-2.bam`; for M2, `M2-3.bam M2-5.bam`. I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62876986/snakemake-how-to-use-glob-wildcards-for-newly-created-files), but I have no idea if there are lots of directories with different files each.

Then I tried to use directories as input, for `merge rule`

```
rule mergebam:
    input:
        "{outpath}/Map/bwa/result/{key}"
    output:
        "{outpath}/Map/bwa/merge/{key}.bam"
    log:
        "{outpath}/Map/bwa/log/{key}.merge.bam.log"
    shell:
        """
        samtools merge {output} `ls {input}/*bam` > {log} 2>&1
        """
```

But this give me `MissingInputException error`

```
Missing input files for rule merge:
/{outpath}/Map/bwa/result/M1
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't fully parsed your question but I'll give it a shot anyway... In rule `merge` you have:

```
expand("{outpath}/Map/bwa/result/{key}/{key}-{value}.bam",outpath=OUTPATH, key=key_ids, value=value_ids)
```

This means that you collect **all** combinations of `outpath`, `key` and `value`.

Presumably you want all combinations of `value` **within** each `outpath` and `key`. So use:

```
expand("{{outpath}}/Map/bwa/result/{{key}}/{{key}}-{value}.bam",  value=value_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks, @dariober Yes, I want all combinations of value within each key and outpath. The `value_ids` print `[3,5,1,2]` also the `Missing input files` will occur in `rule fastp` for `M1-5.R1.fastq.gz and M1-5.R2.fastq.gz`. While `SAMPLES` print `{'M1':[1,2],'M2':[3,5]} `and I really want to get comnination of `[1,2]` for `'M1'` and `[3,5]` for `'M2'`. Sorry if this sounds a stupid question.

Comment: You can also use the keyword argument `allow_missing=True` with expand to limit the double `{{}}`: `expand("{outpath}/Map/bwa/result/{key}/{key}-{value}.bam, value=value_ids, allow_missing=True)`  I prefer this as you can put the path name in a variable or config file and add more wildcards easily.

Answer (score 2):

if you change your config.yaml to the following, can you make the implementation easier by using `expand`?

```
SAMPLES:
  M1:
    - M1-1
    - M2-2
  M2:
    - M2-3
    - M2-5
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks, @Rui Li.